# Zooming with mouse: marquee color

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vcl, teechart

When I use zooming with mouse on a chart (TeeChart) (left button and drag bottom right) cursor draws a marquee rectangle for zoom area. Marquee line is barely visible in light-grey color. Is there any way to change the color of marquee line (something like black, red etc) to make it more contrast and easy to see?

I'm using VCL TChart 4.04.

Comment: You must provide the component name where you are using the zoom

Comment: It's guess the component time. Hiercube?!

Comment: Original question was edited by (moderator?) and component reference along with the tag 'teechart' has been removed. Sorry for that. Restored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is not possible in TChart v.4.04, or at least haven't found any property which might do this.

At least in TChart v.8.03 (the one shipped with Delphi 2009) there are properties `TChart.Zoom.Brush` and `TChart.Zoom.Pen` where you can set the colors and other properties for the selection rectangle. So, if you would have the newer version of TChart you might use something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Chart1.Zoom.Pen.Width := 2;
  Chart1.Zoom.Pen.Color := clRed;
end;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, TChart4.04 does not have 'Zoom' property. The code above fails to compile in DELPHI 7

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible in TChart v.4.04. I've tried to search some property in Delphi 7's TChart for this, but haven't found anything.